# AWS cloud formation template to deploy cloud watch across all AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it feasible for cloud formation template to deploy cloud watch monitoring accross all AZ for all existing instances? Please provide some pointers for the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudWatch is enabled by default for all EC2 instances that are launched in an account.